# How to remove sticker packs in iOS 10

Tags: ios, ios10

I can successfully build sticker pack to iOS into messenger app but I don't know how to remove them. Is it possible on iOS 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just figured it out. We can delete it on the phone by go to sticker list, tap and hold on the collection, then you can tap on the "x" icon to delete it.

[image: Sticker collection list]